# React axios response.json is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I keep receiving an error that response.json is not a function with my axios request data. I am not sure why as this code worked two days ago... I tried messing around with promises to see if that would make a difference but it seems not to The code is below and any help is much appreciated

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import TrackingRender from '../TrackingRender/TrackingRender'
import axios from 'axios'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';


export class OrderTracking extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            loadingData: true,
            order: []
        }
    }
    async componentDidMount() {
        this._isMounted = true;
        if (this.state.loadingData) {
            try {
                const { id } = this.props.match.params
                const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/orders/${id}`)
                const data = await response.json()
                this.setState({
                    order: data,
                    loadingData: false
                })
                console.log(this.state)
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        }

    }
    render() {
        if (!this.state.loadingData) {
            return (
                <div>
                    < TrackingRender order={this.state.order} />
                </div>
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <Redirect to='/orders' />
            )
        }

    }
}

export default OrderTracking
```

Answer (score 7):

With Axios you don't need to run `response.json()` you just get the raw response as is.

The data should be available in `response.data`

Answer (score 0):

To get data from `axios` you need to use `response.data`

```
async componentDidMount() {
        this._isMounted = true;
        if (this.state.loadingData) {
            try {
                const { id } = this.props.match.params
                const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/orders/${id}`)
                const data = await response.data
                this.setState({
                    order: data,
                    loadingData: false
                })
                console.log(this.state)
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `.json()` on an `axios` response. It is already parsed. You can get the value of response body from `response.data`.

```
const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/orders/${id}`)

this.setState({
   order: response.data,
   loadingData: false
})
```